# Get the Document.Url of a WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Programming Environment: Visual Studio 2010
Programming Language: VB.NET

I have a tabbed web-browser that I add dynamically, I `Dim` the the web-browser every-time the user clicks the New Tab button, like this: `browser = New WebBrowser()` and give it a name based on the tab count, e.g. browser2, if there are 2 tab pages. So my question is **-  about time  -** that how would I get the Url of the WebBrowser, I have tried `Dim UrlString As String = CType(tabMain.SelectedTab.Controls.Item(browser.Name), WebBrowser).Url.ToString` But, correct me if I am wrong, I found that WebBrowser isn't classed as a Control, and the reason why I think this is because:

1. This gives me an exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2. So I tried looping through the controls in the `tabMain.SelectedTab` and found that the WebBrowser(browser) isn't included in the collection. The code I used to loop was:

   `For Each ctrl As Control In Me.tabMain.SelectedTab.Controls`
   `MsgBox(ctrl.Name)`
   `Next`

Tried looping through all the Parent controls, but no sign of the WebBrowser showing up. Hope this is enough information =P

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Figured out the problem, really stupid, and my theory was bullshit too =P. Just ignore =] lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
Dim UrlString As String = CType(tabMain.Controls.Item(0), WebBrowser).Url.ToString
```

I assume `tabMain` is the name of the `TabControl`. If this is true and each tab has a `WebBrowser` Control in it then it should work.